# How to parse date and time in android?

Tags: java, android, datetime, parsing, datetime-parsing

I am trying to parse date and time coming from the api. I am getting this kind of response `"ArrivalTime":"\/Date(1543469400000)\/"` .How to parse this response?

Answer (score 2):

The 'envelope' looks like JSON to me, but you didn't paste much. Figure out what it is and get a library that can parse this, so that you end up with a single string that contains just the date part. The `\/` looks bizarre, maybe that's a side effect of how you copy/pasted it. The string you want to end up with has as first character either that `\` or more likely the `D` from Date.

Once you have this:

```
private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\\\/Date\\((\\d+)\\)\\\\/$");
```

This pattern detects `\/Date(any digits here)\/` and lets you extract the digits. If the `\/` aren't in there, remove the 2 `\\\\/`.

Then:

```
String d = "\/Date(1543469400000)\/"; // Get this from your json parser
Matcher m = DATE_PATTERN.matcher(d);
if (!m.matches()) throw new InvalidFormatEx();
long number = Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
Instant n = Instant.ofEpochMilli(number);
```

You now have the right data type - as that number sure looks like epoch-millis to me. It's 'zone less'. Whatever you actually intend to do - start with this instant and go from there.

For example, if you want to print it as a timestamp, zone it to whatever zone you want to print this at, and print it:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = n.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
System.out.println(zdt);
```

If you want to print it in specific formats, make a `DateTimeFormatter` and calls ZDT's `format` method, and so on.

Comment: cannot resolve InvalidFormatEx();

Comment: Yes, duh, that was an example - insert whatever you wish to do if the incoming file has something else there.